# Changing the date format from DD-MM-YYYY to MM-DD-YYYY using react-intl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I'm using react-intl formatDate to convert the date.I need to get the date in "MM-DD-YYYY" format where as I'm getting it in "DD-MM-YYYY" format.Is there any specific way to achieve this?

```
    time value = {
        MyTime.createdTimestamp
    }
    aria - label = {
        formatDate(new Date(Number(MyTime.createdTimestamp)))
    } > {
        formatDate(new Date(Number(MyTime.createdTimestamp)), {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'numeric',
            day: 'numeric'
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric',day: 'numeric'}).format(new Date(Number(MyTime.createdTimestamp)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const today = Date.now();    
 console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(today));
```

Comment: A verbal explanation to what this code does would be helpful

Comment: Also, consider editing the code to spam across multiple lines, so users can see the full code on screen, without requiring scrolling.